# Which movie franchise had the fastest reboot, where both the original and the reboot were shot in the US?

Tags: reboot

Out of all US movie franchises (e.g. Superman, Batman, X-men, etc.), which one had a reboot done after the least amount of time? To specify what a "reboot" is, I'll quote another [related post](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2035/what-was-the-first-instance-of-a-movie-reboot):

> To clarify, the term reboot in this question refers to a movie that:
>
> - differs from the previously existing canon in a significant way, and
> - starts over a continued story of some sort, so more than just one isolated movie.
>
> That's how I would distinguish it from a remake, even though I doubt
>   that this is a definition everyone agrees with.

Comment: too bad for the US restriction. 'La guerre des boutons' and 'la nouvelle guerre des boutons' are both versions of the same story (so technically one could be the reboot of the other) and shipped 7 days apart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually found [this article](https://www.nyfa.edu/student-resources/back-drawing-board-hollywoods-fastest-reboots/) showing the Hollywood's fastest reboots, some of them below:

Name - Original Film Year release - Reboot Year Release

- The Amazing Spider-Man - 2002 - 2012
- Rise of the Planet of the Apes - 1968 - 2001
- Left Behind - 2005 - 2014
- The Incredible Hulk - 2003 - 2008
- Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles - 2007 - 2014

Comment: 10, 33 (!!), 9, 5, and 7. One of those seems a bit out of place.

Comment: And Spider-Man is getting rebooted again.

Comment: Where are you seeing that spiderman is getting rebooted again?

Comment: @Styxsksu That was posted in 2017, so I assume they were referring to *Spider-Man: Homecoming*.

Answer (score 5):

How about the Punisher movies? 2004 and 2008. The second one was intended as a sequel but ended up being a reboot. Also, there was a 1989 Punisher movie, but I'm
not sure it counts. If it does, there are 2 reboots in 19 years.

Answer (score 4):

*[Suicide Sqaud (2016)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1386697/?ref_=ext_shr_lnk)*, followed by *[The Suicide Squad (2021)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6334354/?ref_=ext_shr_lnk)*

Despite the [director's statement](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6334354/trivia?item=tr4867349) to the contrary:

> James Gunn described the film as neither a direct sequel or a reboot
> of the first film, but that "it is what it is". It was ultimately
> accepted to be a standalone sequel.

One of the [producers thought otherwise](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6334354/trivia?item=tr4448950):

> Peter Safran is quoted as saying "First of all, we don't call it
> Suicide Squad 2 'cause it's a total reboot..."